# script does not work unless setInterval() is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am using a simple script which removes the css class from my field .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
  $('#myField').removeAttr('class');
}, 200);
 });
</script>
```

The script only works if I use the setInterval() , without this the script does not work .

Can someone please help me how to execute the script without setInterval() , I guess this behavior occurs because the script executes before the page is fully loaded .

Comment: looks like `myField` is created dynamically... whether the element with id `myField` is present in the html of the page or is it created/loaded via another script

Comment: Where has the element with the ID `myField` been placed?  Was it created using JavaScript or is it in the original HTML?

Comment: I am using this script on an existing application . I place the script on the announcement banner which appears on every page of the application . Yes the field is dynamically generated .

Comment: Since you've put the code inside `$(document).ready()`, it won't execute until the document is loaded, so that's not the problem.

Comment: If the field is dynamically generated, you must run your code after generating it. If it's done using AJAX, put your code in the callback function.

Comment: @Barmar can you give me an example how to do that , I dont have much knowledge about ajax . Thanks

Comment: If you post the code that's creating the element, someone should be able to show how to fix it.

Comment: I guess it is generated from a jsp page .It will be very difficult to find which jsp is reponsible for this .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40153/discussion-between-mizan-and-barmar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the element with an id myField is create dynamically of a script. The problem is that the element may not be created to the 200 milliseconds. Better to do some other testing.
Unfortunately there is no other way, unless you change the surrounding code that creates the element. More preferably the code is written in this way. At least stop interval by removing the element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
 *  @author Georgi Naumov 
 **/
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function handleItem() {
      if($('#myField').length) {
          $('#myField').removeAttr('class');
      } else {
          setTimeout(handleItem, 200);
      }
    }, 200);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks George , I used the http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/ and now I do not need to use the setInterval()